# How do I mount a multi-volume BTRFS filesystem?

Tags: btrfs

I had a btrfs filesystem that consisted of multiple devices. I created it by taking a single device (`/dev/sda`) and running `mkfs.btrfs` on it. I then added 3 more devices to that filesystem (`/dev/sd{b,c,d}`). I then modified that filesystem and the metadata to be in raid10, and then reballanced. I ran this system for a month and then I shut down.

How can I mount this volume again? I assume I don't use `mount /dev/sda /mnt/data` and just ignore that there is now `/dev/sd{b,c,d}` in the filesystem. And I've never seen a mount command that targeted multiple devices for one mount point.

Answer (score 3):

First, run `btrfs filesystem show`, you should see something like this,

```
Label: none  uuid: 33da514a-a666-4c11-b2bd-a5e97372f9a5
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 4.25TiB
    devid    1 size 20.01TiB used 2.13TiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 20.01TiB used 2.13TiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    3 size 20.01TiB used 2.13TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    4 size 20.01TiB used 2.13TiB path /dev/sdc
```

If the device doesn't show, you'll want to run `btrfs device scan --all-devices`

Then you can take that label and mount it it with `mount`

```
mount UUID=33da514a-a666-4c11-b2bd-a5e97372f9a5 /mnt/data/
```

Or, add it to `/etc/fstab` so it happens automatically on boot,

```
mount UUID=33da514a-a666-4c11-b2bd-a5e97372f9a5 /mnt/data/ 0 2
```

Comment: "I assume I don't use `mount /dev/sda /mnt/data`" – I believe you can. You can use any of your four block devices and if the kernel has enough information (i.e. after `btrfs device scan`) then this will work. In `fstab` it's good to use `UUID=` or so anyway, but in a case of ad hoc mounting from an interactive shell you don't have to bother with the UUID, `/dev/sda` should work.